# MVC tkinter model. Switch between frames, add new one

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I am following the [MVC model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter) that Brian made on the answer to “Switch between two frames in tkinter“.
He stacks the frames on top of each other (all are made at the very beginning) and then we just show them at our will.

Is it possible to add another frame once the program has begun to run or only with this model you can view the frames than are made at the start? (Thanks to the answers given I was able to figure how to do it)

But there is still an issue with Page Two, as it is not 100 % independent. Everytime it call the frame it does not start from strach.

The following is the modificactions I made to the code.

```
import tkinter as tk                # python 3
from tkinter import font  as tkfont # python 3
#import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
#import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        # the container is where we'll stack a bunch of frames
        # on top of each other, then the one we want visible
        # will be raised above the others
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

            # put all of the pages in the same location;
            # the one on the top of the stacking order
            # will be the one that is visible.
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        '''Show a frame for the given page name'''
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def add_PageTwo (self):

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', size=18, weight="bold", slant="italic")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        #container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        #container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames["PageTwo"] = PageTwo(parent=container, controller=self)
        self.frames["PageTwo"].grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")        

        self.show_frame("PageTwo")


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is the start page", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)

        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to Page One",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame("PageOne"))
        button2.pack()

class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 1", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the page 2",
                           command=lambda: controller.add_PageTwo())
        button1.pack()
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button2.pack()        

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        label = tk.Label(self, text="This is page 2. GREAT", font=controller.title_font)
        label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Go to the start page",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame("StartPage"))
        button.pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its not an issue to make new frames. If the other frames are either a class attribute or are in something like a list or dict that is an attribute you can add this new frame to an existing frame.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech Thank you. I have (almost) solved that issue as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error lies at the `PageNew` class definition:

```
class PageNew(tk.Frame, parent, controller):
    ...
```

The names in the parentheses are the classes of which `PageNew` will inherit, while you probably meant to pass them as parameters of your `__init__` method.

At this point of the script, `parent` would refer to a module-level variable named `parent`.
However, such a variable does not exist, resulting in a `NameError`.

You need to remove these, and keep only `tk.Frame`.

```
class PageNew(tk.Frame):
    ...
```

As for your question, yes, it is possible to create frames at runtime, and then show them.
They don't need to be all created at initialization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have used it and post my new solution in the question. Almost there ...